# Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I have an error while trying to compile Valhalla application
I was try to compile this code using CMAKE:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
message("   --> PROTOBUF LIB: ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}")
message("   --> PROTOBUF INCLUDE: ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("   --> PROTOBUF VERSION: ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
message("   --> PROTOBUF Found: ${Protobuf_FOUND}")

if(EXISTS protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
  set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
elseif(EXISTS protobuf::libprotobuf)
  set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf)
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined")
endif()
```

This is CMAKE code which gives an error:

```
-- Found Protobuf: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so;-pthread;-pthread (found version "3.6.1")
--> PROTOBUF LIB: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so;-pthread;-pthread
--> PROTOBUF INCLUDE: /usr/local/include
--> PROTOBUF VERSION: 3.6.1
--> PROTOBUF Found: TRUE
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:143 (message):
Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined
```

I don't understand why this code give me an error "Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined"

I was try to change EXISTS on TARGET, but nothing happens, result is the same

```
if(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
 set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
elseif(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf)
 set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf)
else()
 message(FATAL_ERROR "Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined")
endif()
```

Can anyone help me? I was spent about 2 days to solve this

Comment: Keyword `EXISTS` checks for the **file**. For check the target, use `TARGET` keyword instead.

Comment: I was try to use TARGET keyword, but nothing happens

Comment: I use cmake version 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

In the script `FindProtobuf.cmake` of [version 3.7](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindProtobuf.html) there is no notion about `protobuf::*` targets: the script sets only variables. IMPORTED targets are set by the script since [version 3.9](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindProtobuf.html).

Comment: So, do you think i need to set up CMAKE 3.9+ on my server?

Comment: Existence of `IMPORTED` targets is not critical. You may use variables (like `PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES`) as usual.

Comment: Can you please correct my code? so i just can copy and paste it, i don't know CMAKE language as well, I am trying to compile Valhalla program, it's not my own, so i just need to make it compile and work.

Comment: Help me please, my CMAKE skill is below to zero :-((

Comment: As it is *other* code, it is better to not modify it but updating CMake to the required version. Instead of updating entire CMake, you may try to replace original `FindProtobug.cmake` with [newer version](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.9.6/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake), which provides IMPORTED targets. (But I am not sure whether replacing a single file would work).

Comment: It doesn't work, now i will try to install 3.9, i will give feedback later about it

Comment: I was try to install the latest version cmake 3.13, but errors stil exist, i don't know what to do next

Comment: It should work with `TARGET` check. If it doesn't, then something else wrong with the code or with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

After i was build cmake 3.13 and install it i was try to build valhall, but still no result.... i was break my head, but undestood that reason was ">":

```
if(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf-lite>)
  set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)
elseif(TARGET protobuf::libprotobuf>)
  set(valhalla_protobuf_targets protobuf::libprotobuf)
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Required target protobuf::libprotobuf-lite or protobuf::libprotobuf is not defined")
endif()
```

After i delete ">" build was successful!